# What is angle between ray to center of the sun and its perimeter?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, sun

If I took a ray from a point on the earth `P` to the *center* of the sun. And another ray from the same point on the earth to the *perimeter* of the sun. What would the angle between those two rays be?

Also would that angle change based on date, or location of `P` on the earth?

I tried:

```
radius = 696392 km
distance = 1.496e8 km

arcsin(angle) = radius/distance

= 0.2667143488630743 degrees
```

But not sure if that is going to change based on position or date or if there are other factor that affect this.

Comment: You shoud use arctan. You can get minimum & maximum distances at [AstroPixels](http://www.astropixels.com/ephemeris/perap2001.html). And your angular radius value shouldn't have more significant figures than your distance values.

Comment: Indeed. The angle subtended by the Sun (and the Moon) is about 10 milliradians, about half a degree. Varies a bit because of the eccentricity of the orbit of the Earth. The daily variation is probably dominated be refraction of the atmosphere.